# Combining AlternationIndex with Visibility in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, itemscontrol

Here is a style that hides the ListViewItem when bound to a **record** with a property *ALIVE=false*, and then sets the color of the same ListViewItem background based on an **AlternationIndex**:

```
 <Style x:Key="alternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ALIVE}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value= "LemonChiffon"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

The **intent** is to:

1. First, hide all records that have ALIVE set to false
2. Then, apply alternating background colors to the remaining rows.

What **actually** happens:

1. The records with ALIVE set to false are hidden
2. The alternating background is applied to **ALL** rows, thus breaking the alternation
   effect (Eg: instead of getting **yellow/*white*/yellow/*white***, you might get **yellow/yellow/*white*/yellow**)

Now the **question**:

Is it possible to somehow control the AlternationIndex (by telling it to skip rows that should be hidden)?

---

One **alternative** (that I don't like):

Instead of hiding rows with a style, filter out the not ALIVE rows from the underlying collection (that gets bound to the ListView)

Comment: As I understand, hidden items still count when using alteration index and that\`s why alteration colors look like random, but actually are not. I think it\`s easier to work with source collection here like you mentioned, than to invent UI-related solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple LINQ in the getter of your collection property would save you time instead of an UI oriented solution.. Here is how it would look like..

```
    private ObservableCollection<YourClass> _allDataItems;
    //The entire collection
    public ObservableCollection<YourClass> AllDataItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _allDataItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if( _allDataItems == value ) { return; }
            _allDataItems = value;
            if( _allDataItems != null )
            {
                _allDataItems.CollectionChangedEvent += ( s, e ) =>
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged( "DisplayedDataItems" );
                };
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged( "AllDataItems " );
            RaisePropertyChanged( "DisplayedDataItems" );
        }
    }

    //The displayed colelction
    public ObservableCollection<YourClass> DisplayedDataItems
    {
        get
        {
            return AllDataItems.Where( adi => adi.ALIVE == true );
        }
    }
```

And you can simply bind DisplayedDataItems to your ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the most straightforward way would be to filter your data source before binding. However if you are unable to take that course, you could filter your data source in XAML by using an ObjectDataProvider and CollectionViewSource) coupled with your style for alternating row color). See the filtering example here: http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx